# Extends all Joi Validation Package from one file and Import all with const Joi = require('joi')

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

How can i export [joi-phone-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-phone-number) package like [joi-object example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-objectid) under one file and import and use as follows? Following is my validation.js and import in index.js.

```
// validation.js
const Joi = require('joi');
module.exports = function({
  Joi.objectId = require('joi-objectid')(Joi);
  // Here i want to import phone number validation.
})
```

right now, I create two constants to validate objectid and handphone.

```
// schema.js
const Joi = require('joi');
const MyJoi = Joi.extend(require('joi-phone-number')); // I want to add this line in validation.js.
exports.validate = function(data) {
   const schema = {
       name: MyJoi.string().required(),
       hp: MyJoi.string().phoneNumber({ defaultCountry: 'US', format: 'e164})
   }
}
```

I want to put all the Joi packages in one file and import that file to use different types of validation.

```
// What I want to achieve
const Joi = require('joi)
exports.validate = function(data) {
   const schema = {
       id: Joi.ObjectId(),
       name: Joi.string().required(),
       hp: Joi.string().phoneNumber()
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`joi-objectId` looks old and doesn't make use of the `Joi.extend()` api. You can simplify things and free yourself of this dependency. The only thing it does is validate a string with the following:

```
Joi.string().regex(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/);
```

```
// validate.js
const Joi = require("joi");
const MyJoi = Joi.extend(require("joi-phone-number"));

exports.validate = function (data) {
  const schema = {
    id: MyJoi.string().regex(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/),
    name: MyJoi.string().required(),
    hp: MyJoi.string().phoneNumber()
  };

  return MyJoi.validate(data, schema);
};
```